# Find a friend is not working when i connect to lobby first time

Tags: multiplayer, photon, photon-pun, real-time-multiplayer

I want to check the online status of friends when I connect the first time with Photon. The other player can't find me online. But after playing one match, when I rejoin the lobby it finds me online and on the Master server. What's the problem? The Code is given Below.

```
//LOBBY JOINING CODE
    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
        //PhotonNetwork.Disconnect();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Disconnect();
        if (!PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
        {
            Debug.Log("Connecting to Master");
            PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
            //PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        }
        else if (!PhotonNetwork.InLobby && !PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
            PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        }
        if (RoomManager.Instance == null)
        {
            Instantiate(roomManager);
        }

    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to Master");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        Debug.Log("The Server used is : "+PhotonNetwork.Server);

        PhotonNetwork.AuthValues = new AuthenticationValues();
        PhotonNetwork.AuthValues.UserId =PlayerData.userName;
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("title");
        Debug.Log("Joined Lobby");
    }

//Find Friend Code
public void InviteFriend()
    {

        PhotonNetwork.FindFriends(new string[] { "Hammas"});
    }

    public override void OnFriendListUpdate(List<FriendInfo> friendsInfo)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < friendsInfo.Count; i++)
        {
            FriendInfo friend = friendsInfo[i];

            Debug.LogFormat("{0}", friend);
        }
    }
```

This is in the main scene. But the match is on the other scene. When I come back to the main scene from the match, then it works fine. Please describe the reason why it's happening.

I try to reconnect to lobby without matchmaking but still error exits. But when I join lobby after matchmaking then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You set the AuthValues after joining the lobby but you need to set them before connecting. FindFriends relies on a proper, unique userID to find others and this requires the AuthValues be set before connecting.